# The property 'RoleId' on entity type 'UserRole' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my .NET Core application with EF Core I get the following error:

> The property 'RoleId' on entity type 'UserRole' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.'

```
public class UserRole
{
  public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
  public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Why does it suggest to delete the row first and then create a new one. It should only update the role of the object and save it with the new one.

1. I have already tried to set the navigation properties (Role and User) to null, so it needs only to update the RoleId field with the new existing Role.Id.
2. I have tried to update the Role navigation itself with the new one.
   But it doesn't matter.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A table like UserRole is a Many to Many joining table. In EF6 declaring these was optional where as long as the table just contained the UserID and RoleID, your User entity could simply have a Roles collection and the Role could optionally have a Users collection. When set up this way IMO it was easier to understand the limitation in that you wouldn't just take an existing Role reference and try to change it's ID.

AFAIK with EF Core you still need to map the joining table so User will have a collection of UserRoles and you have to navigate through that collection to get to the Roles from the User. Still, the behaviour for many-to-many relationships is the same, you do not modify these references, you need to remove and recreate them.

For instance, given:

```
var user = context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Roles).Single(x => x.UserId == userId);
var newRole = context.Roles.Single(x => x.RoleId == newRoleId);
var userRole = user.UserRoles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RoleId == oldRoleId);

//(Incorrect)
if (userRole != null)
    userRole.Role = newRole;

//(Correct)
if (userRole != null)
    user.UserRoles.Remove(userRole);

user.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { User = user, Role = newRole });
```

Comment: [@Steve Py]: Thanks for the update, can you even tell me how I can determine by reflection if it is a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I have now used: _context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TModel)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Count() == 2. But I think that is not save enough, there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Why would you need to do it by reflection? Your code declares the entity objects and their relationships so the schema and relationships are known to you. Any entity relationships declared /w `HasMany`+`WithMany` relationship is a many-to-many. Composite primary keys do not preclude a many-to-many. Tenancy models (I.e. CustomerId + OrderId) can also use composite PKs.

Comment: Because my page is dynamically build up the index, delete, add/edit and tab pages. The controller only needs to know which fields or links should be present in the grid and/or edit page which I have defined. And all FKs are loaded by reflection, dynamic linq and so on.
Because in general all these controllers using the same actions. For example: I have only 1 index, which is used for all controllers which show the gri with fields. Same for Delete and Edit.